# where condition with data in access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to use date in a where clause. I am building where clause such as this:

```
WhereCondition = WhereCondition + "DOB =" + DOB.value
DoCmd.OpenForm "InputForm", , , WhereCondition
```

DOB is a textbox in current form. I am getting error that type mismatch on the following line:

```
WhereCondition = WhereCondition + "DOB =" + DOB.value
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the concatenation operator for VBA is the ampersand, not a + sign.

So, you should build your string like this:

```
 WhereCondition = WhereCondition & "DOB =" & DOB.value
 DoCmd.OpenForm "InputForm", , , WhereCondition
```

If this does not work, it *may* be necessary to wrap your date in pounds.

```
  WhereCondition = WhereCondition & "DOB =#" & DOB.value & "#"
 DoCmd.OpenForm "InputForm", , , WhereCondition
```

Answer (score 0):

It helps to use # to pass dates:

```
WhereCondition = WhereCondition & "DOB =#" & DOB.value & "#"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use:

```
Dim mySQL as string, WStr as string
mySQL = "DELETE * FROM table"
WStr = " WHERE table.DOB = #" & Forms.*form name*.*control name*.value & "#"
'this will get the value from the form field
mySQL = mySQL & WStr
DoCmd.SetWarnings False 'Prevents message box
DoCmd.runSQL mySQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Obviously you don't have to actually run the query as you could assign a dynamic query string as the record source for a drop down - that would need to be a SELECT query however.